# Can anyone please tell me what's the error by analysing these Heroku logs :

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
2015-10-11T16:48:25.083780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-11T16:48:29.587085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn nextdrop.wsgi --log-file -`
2015-10-11T16:48:31.250453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-10-11T16:48:31.127029+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:28354 (3)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.127131+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345041+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2015-10-11T16:48:31.137466+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345048+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345050+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345051+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345053+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345054+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345056+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345057+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345059+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345060+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345063+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345062+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345066+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345067+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/nextdrop/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345068+00:00 app[web.1]:     from dj_static import Cling
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345065+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345070+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named dj_static
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345071+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345072+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345073+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345075+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345076+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345078+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.254694+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345077+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345080+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-10-11T16:48:31.126285+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345081+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345082+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345083+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345084+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345086+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345087+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/nextdrop/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345088+00:00 app[web.1]:     from dj_static import Cling
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345089+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named dj_static
2015-10-11T16:48:31.345153+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432647+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432651+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432653+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432654+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432655+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432657+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432658+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432659+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432664+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432665+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432663+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432667+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432668+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/nextdrop/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432660+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432661+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432669+00:00 app[web.1]:     from dj_static import Cling
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432673+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432694+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432672+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432693+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432670+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named dj_static
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432697+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432696+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432698+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432699+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432703+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432706+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432700+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432710+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named dj_static
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432705+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432702+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2015-10-11T16:48:31.460755+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432707+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/nextdrop/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432708+00:00 app[web.1]:     from dj_static import Cling
2015-10-11T16:48:31.432716+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 16:48:31 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.460761+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466461+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466478+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466471+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466472+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466479+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 201, in run
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466474+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466475+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466481+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466477+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466482+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 297, in halt
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466501+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466483+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466500+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in stop
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466502+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 214, in handle_chld
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466504+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466505+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466506+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-10-11T16:48:31.466508+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-10-11T16:48:32.366965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-10-11T16:48:32.321211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-10-11T16:48:43.770304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-river-6098.herokuapp.com request_id=57039b3f-2432
-4ede-bd37-fd9351932985 fwd="103.25.1.30" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-10-11T16:48:17.500768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-10-11T16:48:47.335609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-river-6098.herokuapp.com request_id=65
288dc0-c793-40d0-8562-ace41bf63ed8 fwd="103.25.1.30" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31353681/2744166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module named `dj_static`.